# Export a value outside a SQL query (Callback Hell)

Tags: mysql, node.js, discord.js

My goal is to set `someVar` to 1 if my SQL query finds a result.
The problem is that the assignment is local and when I try a `console.log(someVar)`, the result is 1 inside the block, but 0 outside it. Is there a way to export the value outside it?

```js
let someVar = 0;
con.query(`SOME SQL QUERY`, (error, rows) => {
    if (error) throw error
    if (rows.length > 0) {
        someVar = 1;
        //console.log(someVar) -> The result is 1
    }
});
con.end();
//console.log(someVar) -> The result is 0

if (someVar === 0) {
    // Some code
}
```

Comment: It's  a callback, not being executed synchronously.

Comment: http://callbackhell.com/

Comment: Okay I'll watch your site, thanks for your help ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to fredrik I fixed it.
I finally used promise like that

```
let promiseQuery = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    con.query(`SOME SQL QUERY`, (error, results, fields) => {
        if (error) reject(error);
        resolve(results || {});
    })

})
const someVar = promiseQuery.length
if (someVart === 0) {
    // Some code
} else {
    // Some code
}
```